# Why both PolicySet and Policy are needed?

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, xacml3, xacml2

I've read through the 3.0 specs and had a question here:

I found **PolicySet** and **Policy** share many similarities like the combining algorithms, etc. And to accommodate more levels, **PolicySet** also can be self-containable. If so, why not merge **PolicySet** and **Policy** into a single concept named **Policy** and make Policy contain other Policies and Rules?

---

**Update**:

Speaking of **Rule**, actually **Rule** doesn't differ with **Policy** much either, except that **Rule** has **Condition** and **Effect** and doesn't have a **combining algorithm**. What I am thinking of now is merging the three conceptions: **PolicySet, Policy, Rule** into a single new **Policy**. This **Policy** is self-containable and can has its **Condition** and **Effect**. If its combining algorithm returns **Intermediate**, then use its own **Effect**. The whole policy is not applicable if its own **Condition** fails to meet the request. I personally think **this one-concept model is more concise and clear than the PolicySet, Policy and Rule.**

For example, for a **four-level policy** (if there's a demand for a four-level policy for a big enterprise), XACML will represent like:

`PolicySet -> PolicySet(s) -> Policy(s) -> Rule(s)`

My modification would be:

`Policy -> Policy(s) -> Policy(s) -> Policy(s)`

Compared to the XACML's **two-level PolicySets and a level Policy and Rule**, I think a straightforward **four-level Policies** would be clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact both exist is a quirk of the language. You could imagine a language with a leaf element (the rule) and a branch (the policy).

Both Policy and PolicySet are very similar. When modeling in XACML you can assimilate them.

You'd have a policy that can contain other policies XOR rules but not both at the same time

## EDIT

Following the OP's edit, here is a bit more context.

### XACML Structural Elements

XACML introduces 3 structural elements:

- PolicySet (PS)
- Policy (P)
- Rule (R)

As the OP states, PolicySet can contain Policy and PolicySet thus allowing for an overall tree that is as deep as the author wants it to be (PS --> PS --> PS ... --> P --> R).

### Contents of PolicySet, Policy, and Rule

All three elements (PS, P, R) can contain:

- Target elements: the target is what defines the scope of the element. A target is made up of an AND/OR/AND structure and attribute matches e.g. `role=='manager' OR role=='editor'`.
- Obligations & advice: obligations and advice are statements that are returned along with a decision from the PDP (policy decision point) back to the PEP (policy enforcement point)

### Combining Algorithms

Because PolicySet and Policy elements can contain children, they need a mechanism to resolve conflicts between children. That mechanism is called a combining algorithm. Therefore both PolicySet elements and Policy elements have a combining algorithm property. Since PolicySets contain other PolicySets and/or Policy elements, the combining algorithm in a PolicySet is called a *policy combining algorithm*. Since Policy elements contain Rules only, the combining algorithm is called a rule combining algorithm.

Another quirk of XACML is that the list of combining algorithms for policies is nearly almost the same as for rules. The notable differences are:

- only-one-applicable exists only for policies.
- on-permit-apply-second exists only for policies.

Here is the list in the [ALFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALFA_(XACML)) notation (ALFA is a pseudo-language developed by [Axiomatics](http://www.axiomatics.com/solutions/products/authorization-for-applications/developer-tools-and-apis/192-axiomatics-language-for-authorization-alfa.html) to simplify XACML policy authoring):

```
namespace System {
    ruleCombinator denyOverrides = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides"
    ruleCombinator permitOverrides = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:permit-overrides"   
    ruleCombinator firstApplicable = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable"
    ruleCombinator orderedDenyOverrides = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:ordered-deny-overrides"
    ruleCombinator orderedPermitOverrides = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:ordered-permit-overrides"
    ruleCombinator denyUnlessPermit = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-unless-permit"
    ruleCombinator permitUnlessDeny = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:permit-unless-deny"

    policyCombinator denyOverrides = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:policy-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides"
    policyCombinator permitOverrides = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:policy-combining-algorithm:permit-overrides"
    policyCombinator firstApplicable = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:policy-combining-algorithm:first-applicable"
    policyCombinator onlyOneApplicable = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:policy-combining-algorithm:only-one-applicable"
    policyCombinator orderedDenyOverrides = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:policy-combining-algorithm:ordered-deny-overrides"
    policyCombinator orderedPermitOverrides = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:policy-combining-algorithm:ordered-permit-overrides"
    policyCombinator denyUnlessPermit = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:policy-combining-algorithm:deny-unless-permit"
    policyCombinator permitUnlessDeny = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:policy-combining-algorithm:permit-unless-deny"
    policyCombinator onPermitApplySecond = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:policy-combining-algorithm:on-permit-apply-second"
}
```

### Targets & Conditions

#### Targets

As previously stated, Target elements can exist in any of PolicySet, Policy, and Rule. A Target has a set structure of AND/OR/AND elements to combine together attribute matches i.e. the comparison of a given attribute to a given value. XACML provides a long list of functions that can be used.

In a target only functions that take 2 atomic values and return a boolean can be used e.g. == (or urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal). Other functions e.g. sum (urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:integer-add) cannot be used.

#### Conditions

In particular, there is one ***really useful*** thing Target elements cannot do: compare two attributes together i.e. establish a relationship. Imagine for instance you want to write a Policy that states:

> Doctors can view the medical record of a patient they are assigned to.

Or in other words, `Permit if userId == assignedDoctorId`.

This is where Condition elements kick in. A Condition is an expression that can use any function available in XACML. The overall outcome of the Condition must be a boolean but now you can do things like `sum(age, limit)>5` or `userId == assignedDoctorId`.

And here comes another quirk: Condition elements can only be used inside a Rule element. So, if you want to express a relationship in XACML, you will need to have at least one Rule. And since a Rule element cannot live on its own. You will have to have at least one Policy element.

So the smallest possible XACML policy is (using ALFA):

```
namespace example{
    policy policyExample{
        apply denyOverrides
        rule allowAll{
            permit          
        }
    }
}
```

And the resulting XACML XML code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!--This file was generated by the ALFA Plugin for Eclipse from Axiomatics AB (http://www.axiomatics.com). 
 Any modification to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source ALFA file-->
<xacml3:Policy xmlns:xacml3="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"
    PolicyId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/example.policyExample"
    RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides"
    Version="1.0">
    <xacml3:Description />
    <xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
        <xacml3:XPathVersion>http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116</xacml3:XPathVersion>
    </xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
    <xacml3:Target />
    <xacml3:Rule 
            Effect="Permit"
            RuleId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/example.policyExample.allowAll">
        <xacml3:Description />
        <xacml3:Target />
    </xacml3:Rule>
</xacml3:Policy>
```